# Redundant use of .delete()

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to create a method that renames a log file in a data collection program, but there is an `IOException` that is thrown (infrequently) when trying to access the log file shortly after accessing it once (for a second trace of data).

I do not know if it is because of the call to `.delete()` or if I have to make sure the file is closed before accessing it.  I am really stuck on this one.  Here is the method I am working on.

```
public static void renameFile(String oldName, String newName) throws IOException
{
    File srcFile = new File(oldName).getAbsoluteFile();
    boolean bSucceeded = false;
    try 
    {
        File destFile = new File(newName).getAbsoluteFile();
        if (destFile.exists()) 
        {
            if (!destFile.delete()) 
            {
                throw new IOException(oldName + " was not successfully renamed to  " + newName + ", could not perform !destFile.delete()");                 
            }
        }
        if (!srcFile.renameTo(destFile))
        {
            throw new IOException(oldName + " was not successfully renamed to " + newName + ", could not rename source file");          
        } 
        else 
        {
            bSucceeded = true;
        }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (bSucceeded) 
        {
            srcFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace of your exception?

Answer (score 2):

The code seems Ok, but as you mentioned, you must make sure to close the file before calling this method. On Unix, this may work, but on Windows you definetly cannot rename or delete a file which has an open file descriptor.

Comment: Thanks that really helps!  I'll make sure to implement a .close() on the file